# PyCharm does not find installed submodule

Tags: python, module, pytorch, pycharm

I am trying to use DISK feature matching in my application: https://github.com/cvlab-epfl/disk
I setup my PyCharm project locally on Windows 10 in C:/Workspace/SFM.
DISK is recursively cloned into C:/Workspace/SFM/disk and I ran `pip install --user -r requirements.txt` in my PyCharm terminal.
In my `main.py` function I am calling DISK such as:

```
def disk_feature_matching(input_dir, disk_path, output_dir):

    disk_feature_detection = os.path.join(disk_path, 'detect.py')

    cmd = f'python {disk_feature_detection} {output_dir} {input_dir}'

    print(f'Running DISK on {input_dir}')
    subprocess.run(cmd.split())

    print('DISK feature matching completed.')



def main():

    input_dir = 'data'
    output_dir_disk = 'disk-results'

    # Create the output directory if it doesn't exist.

    if not os.path.exists(output_dir_disk):
        os.makedirs(output_dir_disk)

    disk_path = 'disk'
    disk_feature_matching(input_dir, disk_path, output_dir_disk)
```

The error I get is:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "C:/Arbeit/Workspace/HAI-SFM/disk/detect.py", line 7, in 
> from torch_dimcheck import dimchecked ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'torch_dimcheck'

In `detect.py` it is imported as:
`from torch_dimcheck import dimchecked` and marked as unsolved reference.
It seems that it is successfully installed but PyCharm does not find it.
I tried setting the directory as source but then the other packages are not found anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to find the answer in three steps.

### First step: Correctly install submodules

It seems that the submodule was not installed correctly at first.
I had to navigate to the `submodules` directory and run `pip install` to use the existing `setup.py`.
Then the submodules finally appeared in the Python Interpreter.
However, the error above still occured.

### Second step: Clear PyCharm cache

I could fix it by running **File -> Invalidate Caches -> Clear file system cache and Local History** and press `Invalidate and Restart` in PyCharm.

### Third step: Set interpreter path

After reloading, sometimes the module still cannot be found. I went to **Settings->Python Interpreter->Show All...->Show paths for the selected interpreter** and added the path to the submodule in Interpreter Paths.